# c++ vector push back in a class

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to compile the following code but the message "no matching function for call to 'std::vector::push_back(double&)'" keep coming up. Can anyone help me to solve it please?

```
struct Booking
{
   double bT;
   double aT;
   double dT;
};

class New
{
private:
    std::vector<Booking> vectorBookings;

public:

    void gB(double bR,double aR, double dR,double startTime,double finishTime)
    {
        double bT;
        do
        {   
            bT   = startTime   - (1.0/bR);
        } while(bT<finishTime);

        double aT   = bT - (1.0/aR);
        double dT = aT - (1.0/dR); 

        vectorBookings.push_back(bT,aT, dT);
    }  
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You would have to add `{}` to construct a `Booking` to `push_back`

```
vectorBookings.push_back({bT,aT, dT});
```

Comment: [`emplace_back` doesn't work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/522b27e1afa561fd). I believe it uses parentheses for initialization rather than braces.

Comment: @chris, perfect catch. I wonder if it is a defect or intentional behaviour.

Comment: @SergeyA, Very likely intentional. When designing functions that initialize objects, this choice has to be made. There was a blog post or something "recently" discussing this choice in relation to `std::optional`.

Comment: I have another question. When I try to insert some values for my member functin gB in the main function, it says "no match for 'operator<<", how can I solve it?

Comment: @Shawn You would have to show that snippet of code where you try to do that. If your current question is resolved, and you have another, feel free to post a new question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Daniel, The answer used to include it as an option :)

Answer (score 1):

If you define a constructor for `Booking` you can use `emplace_back`:

```
struct Booking
{
    Booking(double bT, double aT, double dT) : bT {bT}, aT {aT}, dT {dT} {}
    double bT, aT, dT;
};
```

Then just change `vectorBookings.push_back(bT, aT, dT)` to `vectorBookings.emplace_back(bT, aT, dT)`.